# Bash: How do I round a variable down to the next even number?

Tags: bash, shell

Say I've got an integer variable from a parameter `$1` that's 1025.

I need it to be 1024. How can I round it down?

Comment: It needs to round to down the next even number. The result must always be even.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
round() {
    echo $(( ${1:?need one argument} / 2 * 2))
}

round 1025
1024

round 1024
1024
```

Comment: The number needs to be even, that's the restriction

Comment: Nope, this will make a number round-down so `1025` will become `1024` and `1024` will remain `1024`.

Comment: Or, more succinctly: `round_even() { echo $(( ${1:?need one argument} / 2 * 2)); }` where the semicolon isn't needed if you use multiple lines for the function, which isn't an option in a comment.  I assume the argument detection code works in an arithmetic expression; if not, use an assignment as in your code.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, I edited with your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You can write [arithmetic expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) with this syntax:

```
$(( expr ))
```

So you'd want something like:

```
$(( $1 - ($1 % 2) ))
```

Comment: I get ./res.sh: 4: ./res.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "2049 - "
when trying to round down 2049 - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(( $(echo $var%2|bc) != 0 )) && ((var--))
echo $var
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `$var--`?

Comment: @beresfordt Nope, `(($var--))` shows error. `((var--))` or `((var=$var-1))` or `((var=var-1))` or `((var-=1))` are all correct.